# What is the purpose of the .git file in some project code directory?

Tags: git

The project has a Lib subdirectory where there are multiple libraries' zip files. Each file is extracted into its own directory, but directories have `.git` file inside each. If I open it, there is some path starting with `gitdir:`.

For example, this is the project structure

```
rootDir/  
  --Subdir A/
  --Subdir B/
  --lib/
      --Library.zip
      --mylibrary dir/
           --subdir x
           --subdir y
           --.git
```

The path in the `.git` file says `gitdir: ../../.git/modules/lib/mylibrary`

Obviously, this file tells where the module git files are. However, I cannot push because of it and I get an error message like "there is no git in mylibrary directory". If I remove the `.git` file, I can push.

Note: I have used Git hundreds of times in dozens of projects and I had never faced any error like this, not I had even seen `.git` file in the library directories.

Comment: Is there a correct .git in this directory? what dies git status tell you about the changes made if any?

Comment: Please do NOT edit .git file to .git directoy as I don't have .git/ directory, but a .git file!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `.git` indicates that this folder is a git working tree and under git version control.

- If `.git` is a folder, all git data is directly stored inside that directory.
- If `.git` is a file, it contains the path to its data directory (the path can be relative) - this is usually used for submodules where the data directory of the submodule is nested inside the data directory of the parent.

Regarding your problem: Does the path mentioned in the `.git` file exist? - Maybe someone added the .git file in the .zip file by mistake.

Comment: Yes, this is a submodule. There is also a file `.gitmodules` in the root directory. I guess I have never seen it before because I have never used remote submodules with its own git before.

Comment: Yes, the path exists. I will handle the error now that I know the purpose of the .git file.